# Access tokens and offline application after approval

Tags: javascript, facebook-access-token

Right hello there,

I have recently come to find out they are removing offline access for publishing on the 5th December and need a hand with a quick question and a possible solution would be appreicated.

Basically I wish to develop a facebook application which users will sign in and grant permissions for the application via JS.

The application will be used by them in a few hours or several days time as the facebook login is in the booking process. When they play the game, I wish to post updates to their news feed and any of the friends playing with them that auth'ed the facebook application and the token is active.

How would this be possible with Facebook's current SDK.

During the game, they user cannot view facebook on any of the devices so thats why offline_access would have been perfect

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Offline access on Facebook api was just on the cases where your app could be used offline.

To facebook, it doesn't matter if you are showing the FB interface or not. you are not obligated to display to a user the actions that you are doing, (for example a "like")

You can also override the default implementation, like on "share", you can add your own code to do it.

So basically you never needed the "offline_access"